# How to make .Contains() search for the texted typed in a textbox anywhere in the field C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, contains

In the code below, `.Contains()` only return string that start with the text I type in the `TextBox`. I want it to return all records that contain that string anywhere in the the searched field. Please advise how I can get `Contains()` to return the value, alternate ways are welcome as well

Thanks

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())            
{                    
     foreach (var Current in GC.IMF_Extensions.Where(filter => filter.Description.Contains(Search_txt.Text) ))
     {
          string sss = Current.Description;
          Coll.Add(sss);
     }
     // tried same result foreach (var Current in GC.IMF_Extensions.Where(filter => filter.Description.Contains(Search_txt.Text.Trim()) || filter.Description.StartsWith(Search_txt.Text) || filter.Description.EndsWith(Search_txt.Text)))
     // tried same result foreach (var Current in GC.IMF_Extensions.Where(filter => filter.Description.Contains(Search_txt.Text.Trim()) ))
}
```

Comment: contains should do the work . can you provide a example what you wants but what's is showing ?

Comment: Please update your sample to be standalone - include constant values for input, and try to remove custom types from posted sample. So far code should be doing what you want and there is no way for people without debugger attached to your code to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a simpler method without Linq:

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())            
{                    
    foreach (var Current in GC.IMF_Extensions)
    {
        if (Current.Description.Contains(Search_txt.Text))
        {
            Coll.Add(Current.Description);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Philippe. I did and it helped me see that Contains() does return the correct record. I duplicated the code and put it in a button and debugged + add watch and saw.  I think I have to check the textbox properties i .e. autocomplete.

Comment: Glad I helped, if that suffices to be an answer, please mark this answer as the correct one

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ToLower` for both strings before `Contains`. It should be work.

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())            
{                    
     foreach (var Current in GC.IMF_Extensions.Where(filter => filter.Description.ToLower().Contains(Search_txt.Text.ToLower())))
     {
          Coll.Add(Current.Description);
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you X-TECH. I tried this as well. My problem looks related to the textbox auto complete properties. The Coll array contains the correct info but the suggestions do not reflect it on the textbox, it only suggests when the text sought is the the first word in the field.